# Something is making pops and clicks in the background of my computer

Tags: windows-7, audio, memory, ssd

I have a dedicated music computer. I am running sonar as the DAW. I do not usually use a microphone in, but, every time I do, I get pops and clicks.  I have done all of the Windows adjustment, so that isn't the problem.  Recently, I opened my Mixer (Attached to my RME Audio Multiface II) Even when I have nothing open, the first 8 inputs on my mixer are jumping around like popcorn.  I am at a loss.  I disabled almost every service I could, and  it is still happening.  I first noticed this about 6 months ago. At that point it was intermittent – there might be a pop or click every 10 seconds.  Now it is popcorn.  Could this be memory going bad, or maybe a hard drive problem?

- Windows 7 Pro 64-bit
- 32 GB RAM
- 5 SSDs and one Velociraptor drive
- Gigbyte motherboard
- RME Audio – as described above.

Any one have an idea?

Comment: Does it have a wireless (WLAN adapter)? Disable it from Device Manager or physically remove it, if it does. Same goes for your Ethernet adapter, but start by unplugging the Ethernet cable. Problems like these are usually caused by electrical interference and hardware interrupts, and network adapters are the usual suspects.

Answer (score 0):

Its more likely to be an issue with the power and or PSU then the memory or SSD.  It could also be an issue (like a blown/dodgy cap) on the motherboard.

Also - especially if you have your interfaces connected to another [ non-optical ] device, maybe there is an issue with grounding.